# Arcgis 10.0 desktop: how to clear All transformations from map

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

I have a custom extension which adds some custom transformations to the map. When turned off, the extension is supposed to remove all the added transformations.
However, when calling `IGeoTransformationOperationSet.RemoveAll()`, nothing happens. The transformations are removed from the set but nothing changes in the map - the transformed features stay in the same place and do not move back to their original position.

I'm using Arcgis desktop 10.0 and my code is written in c#.

How can I turn off/on the custom transformations? What am I missing?
Thanks.

Comment: Stupid question, but you are forcing a refresh of the data frame/active view, right?

Comment: Not stupid at all, and yes I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there are two GeoTransformationOperationSet objects and you should remove both of it. The sample code is,

```
//Remove from Map Object
IMapGeographicTransformations pMapGeoTrans = pMap as IMapGeographicTransformations;
IGeoTransformationOperationSet pGeoTransSet =  pMapGeoTrans.GeographicTransformations;
pGeoTransSet.RemoveAll();

//Remove from SpatialReferenceEnvironment Object
ISpatialReferenceFactory2 pSRF = new SpatialReferenceEnvironmentClass();
pGeoTransSet = pSRF.GeoTransformationDefaults;
pGeoTransSet.RemoveAll();

//Refresh view
IActiveView pActiveView = pMap as IActiveView;
pActiveView.Refresh();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks, It works now. I needed to remove the transformations from the spatial reference environment class.